# Make an iframe (or similar) load its content through a websocket proxy?

Tags: javascript, iframe, websocket

I would like to display a existing sub-site in an iframe.

The twist is that I would like the content to be served via a custom Websocket http proxy.  The server-side of the Websocket would handle retrieving the original sub-site content via http from the origin server.

I assume that all iframe browser (and Ajax) resource loading calls would need to be intercepted and satisfied by some Javascript code, which would get the needed resources via a Websocket connection.

Is this plain impossible?

Comment: Hmm If i understood you corecctly,I dont think this is impossible, but depending what you want to do, isnt it enought to create a .php file on a webserver which loads what you need over `file_get_contents()`? It would also ouput the <iframe>-Tags but enabling JavaScript in such an envoirement destroy almost anything what a proxy could give you depending on privay.

Comment: @KoalaGangsta Yes, I was looking for all iframe (regular and javascript-initiated comms) to be intercepted and fulfilled by outer-page javascript/websockets.

Comment: Wrote a new answer instead of this crappy written comment, hope it what you meant :)

Comment: @KoalaGangsta Sorry, my typo confused you, there was a bracket in the wrong place: "Yes, I was looking for all iframe (regular and javascript-initiated) comms to be intercepted and fulfilled by outer-page javascript/websockets."

Comment: That confused me even more xD (My english reeeeeeally sucks) Sooo, you want to get every iframe, and depending on something you want to show your specific things into this iframe? If i still understood in wrong rell me in ASM x86 pls xD

Answer (score 1):

When I got your problem correctly you try to get a web document and remove all the `<iframe>`-Tags.

You can do this by getting reading the page by `file_get_contents()` and removing all `<iframe>`-Tags by its pattern using preg_replace()

```
<?php
$content = file_get_contents('http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_iframe.asp');
echo preg_replace('/<iframe(|\/)(?!\?).*?(|\/)>/','', $content);
?>
```

**Note:** As some requests without a base URL (for example `<img src="...`) will look the for the resources on your server the site will not render correctly.

*dran you stackoverflow! one day i will know your formitting... :x*

Comment: Sorry, I didn't explain it well.  I want to put an `<iframe>` on example.com which gets its content by asking the the page's Javascript for content, rather than using the browser to get the content.